# Reference error: is not defined, when trying to send data with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

so I'm trying to send an array as a string to a .php file to write it into a database, and I get this error `ReferenceError: strings is not defined`

don't really know what's going on, first time doing this. I copied code from a tutorial and started altering it, it worked well until I added the strings after name. Are these words reserved, what should I use for this and how does it work? Thanks for the help.

```js
var string = [1, 2, 3];

$('#write').click(function() {
  writeTable();
})

// handles the click event, sends the query
function writeTable() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'write.php',
    type: 'get', //data type post/get
    data: {
      name: $('input#input').val(),
      strings: JSON.stringify(strings)
    },
    complete: function(response) {
      $('.output').html(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.output {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

</head>

<body>

  <br>
  <form>File Name:
    <input type="text" id="input" name="input" placeholder="Type something">
  </form>
  <br>
  <div class="button" id="write">Write</div>
  <div class="button" id="search">Search</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="output"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You never define `strings`, so `strings` is not defined. (You do define a variable called `string`, though; is this a one-character typo?)

Comment: The problem is probably that `strings` is not defined. Hey, these error messages, they are often quite helpful. Why do you think `strings` would be defined. Where do you think it is coming from? What is it supposed to contain? It would be undefined whether or not you are trying to send data with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare : `var string = [1, 2, 3];`

and put `strings: JSON.stringify(strings)`

You just have a `s` missing or one to remove :

To fix this you can change :

```
strings: JSON.stringify(strings)
```

To (2nd "string" without **s**):

```
strings: JSON.stringify(string)
```